# Is there a server-side session in meteor

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

I have a meteor site in which the login process is done via github. Github has a a very easy API and I can easily do this. However, when this authentication process is done, I have no idea how to validate requests made by the client. I think I need to use the collection's `allow` and `deny` methods, but how do I know which user made the request. I haven't seen any cookie information. Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1):

`allow` and `deny` pass the userId along with the object trying to be updated...

We do it like this:

```
Fundraiser.allow({
  insert: function (userId, fundraiser) {
    return userId;
  },

  update: function (userId, fundraiser, fields) {
    return fundraiser.userId === userId;
  },

  remove: function (userId, fundraiser) {
    return fundraiser.userId === userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: You think someone who only knows JavaScript, and not CoffeeScript, understands your example?

Comment: The point is the `userId`. How do you populate the `user` collection and how do you setup meteor to use it. I think the solution lies in `accounts-base` and/or `accounts-github`. I haven't had time to figure out how these work

Comment: I think this screencast explains it all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CTSGdQOYYg

Comment: I've continued the implementation of accounts-github [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078912/meteor-setup-accounts-github-not-working?noredirect=1#comment37134649_24078912)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, and its default expiration time is [90 days](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config):

`console.log("sessions:", Meteor.user().services.resume.loginTokens)`

Unfortunately `services.resume.loginTokens` is not valid for storage according to Mongo, so use [UserSession](https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-user-session).