# Meteor: setup accounts-github not working

Tags: authentication, meteor, github-api

I'm trying to setup authentication using github.
I followed the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/). I've installed the packages:

```
$> meteor add accounts-github
$> meteor add service-configuration
```

And my code in `server/github.js` looks like:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: "github"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "github",
    clientId: '****',
    secret: '*************'
});

Meteor.loginWithGithub({
    requestPermissions: ['user', 'public_repo']
}, function (err) {
      if (err)
        Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
});
```

When I start meteor now I get the following error:

```
/Users/me/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loginWithGithub'
at app/server/github.js:11:8
at app/server/github.js:18:3
....
```

So it seems the `Meteor` object doesn't have the `loginWithGithub` method. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Why are you trying to login from the server? `Meteor.loginWithGithub` only exists on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the code in the `/server` directory of your app.

Usually you call this code from the web browser to make Meteor display the Github OAuth login dialog.

This is not available on the server since its only meant to work on the browser side. This is why you see this error.

You would usually fire `Meteor.loginWithGithub()` in the event listener for when they click a button or some UI element to begin the login process.

Another thing to keep in mind is `Session` (`Session.get`, `Session.set`, etc) only work on the client too.

To see which methods run where use the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com). In the top corner of each method it shows where the code can run: Client, Server or Anywhere.